# Wordpress echo post subcategory

Tags: wordpress

So I'm echoing an array of posts as titles. 
Each post belongs to a specific category and subcategory, in order to use those titles for loading all posts from the subcategory to which this title belongs with ajax. 
I need to echo the id of only the subcategory of each title. 
Please help! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   foreach((get_the_category($post->ID)) as $childcat) {
      echo $childcat->cat_name . '</a>';
  }

if you have some key for subcategories,  You can classify categories as below.
foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
  if (cat_is_ancestor_of(10, $childcat)) {
   echo $childcat->cat_name . '</a>';
  }
}
```